# lag shift Funtion in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to shift the number of orders by in range from 1 to 7. Here is my python **code** :

```
def make_features(data, max_lag):    
    for lag in range(1, max_lag + 1):
        data['lag_{}'.format(lag)] = data['num_orders'].shift(lag)

make_features(df, 7)
```

I try to do the same think in Pyspark : **Code** :

```
def make_features(data, max_lag):    
    for lag in range(1, max_lag + 1):
        data['lag_{}'.format(lag)] = data['num_orders'].shift(lag)

make_features(df, 7)
```

I get this **error** :

```
    TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I also try this **code** :

```
for lag in range(1, 8):
    window = Window.orderBy("date")
    lagCol = lag(col("num_orders"), n).over(window)
    df.withColumn(f"LagCol_{n}", lagCol)
```

This  it just shift by 1 unit :

Expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PySpark, there is no `shift` function as you expected, and you were in the right direction when using `lag`. But there is a little trick here when you have to do `lag_2` based on `lag_1` and so on.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

df = df.withColumn('lag_0', F.col('num_orders'))
for lag in range(1, 8):
    df = (df
        .withColumn(f'lag_{lag}', F
            .lag(f'lag_{lag - 1}')
            .over(W
                .partitionBy(F.lit(1))
                .orderBy('date')
            )
        )
    )


+----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|date|num_orders|lag_0|lag_1|lag_2|lag_3|lag_4|lag_5|lag_6|lag_7|
+----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   1|       124|  124| null| null| null| null| null| null| null|
|   2|        85|   85|  124| null| null| null| null| null| null|
|   3|        71|   71|   85|  124| null| null| null| null| null|
|   4|        66|   66|   71|   85|  124| null| null| null| null|
|   5|        43|   43|   66|   71|   85|  124| null| null| null|
|   6|         6|    6|   43|   66|   71|   85|  124| null| null|
|   7|        12|   12|    6|   43|   66|   71|   85|  124| null|
+----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```